# Ajax call to a MongoDB query in a JQuery each loop is affecting the order of results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to run an AJAX call that executes a mongoDB query and returns sorted results within a JQuery each loop. The sorted database results do not get appended to a list in the correctly returned order. Some of the results that have `has_users` set to `true` are appended to the list in incorrect positions. If I remove the itemQuery() function call to the AJAX/MongoDB functionality, the list items are appended in the correct sorted order. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
$.each(items, function (i, item) {
    //itemQuery() holds ajax call that runs mongoDB query and returns sorted results
    itemQuery(item._id).done(function(data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            has_users = true;
        } else {
            has_users = false;
        }

        listItem = buildListItem(item, has_users);
        $('#list_dropdown').append(listItem);
    });

});
```

Comment: `$.each` is synchronous, so all the Ajax calls are basically kicked off at once. The elements are appended in the order the Ajax calls receive the responses, which is not deterministic.

Comment: Can't you make a `json` list and send all the IDs in one ajax request? you are making a lot of traffic on your server with this code depending on the number of items

Answer (score 4):

Some of the Ajax calls finish before the others, so you get wrong order. You can use [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) instead of `$.each()`, return a Promise, and use [`$.when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to wait for all the promises to complete and then append the elements.

Your code could be something like this:

```
$.when(
  $.map(items, function (i, item) {
    //itemQuery() holds ajax call that runs mongoDB query and returns sorted results
    return itemQuery(item._id).done(function(data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            has_users = true;
        } else {
            has_users = false;
        }

        return buildListItem(item, has_users);
    });
  })
).then(function (elements) {
  $('#list_dropdown').append(elements);
});
```